# Orchard CMS--Can't view fields of custom type

Tags: content-management-system, orchardcms

I am learning Orchard CMS and tried to create a custom type. I followed various tutorials, creating the Model classes and Migration.cs, and was able to see my part show up under the listed Content Parts on Orchard.

[image]

I then added a driver, handler, views, and placement.info. However, I am not able to see the fields of my new part when I create or view an item that contains my part -- the item is empty where my part's fields should be.

[image]

Here is my Views/Parts/Event.cshtml:

```
@using Orchard.ContentManagement.ViewModels
@using Orchard.ContentManagement
@using Orchard.Core.Common.Models
<div class="event-container">
    <div class="event-text">
        <p>Event Name: @Model.EventName</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Event ID: @Model.EventID</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Description: @Model.Description</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my Views/EditorTemplates/Event.cshtml:

```
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@using Orchard.Event.Models
@model Orchard.Event.Models.EventPart
<fieldset>
    <legend>@T("Event Fields")</legend>

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.EventName, T("Event Name"))
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.EventName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.EventName)
    </div>
    <div class="hint">@T("Enter the Event Name")</div>

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.EventID, T("Event ID"))
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.EventID)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.EventID)
    </div>
    <div class="hint">@T("Enter the Event ID")</div>

     <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Description, T("Description"))
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Description)
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Description)
    </div>
    <div class="hint">@T("Enter the Description")</div>

</fieldset>
```

Driver:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Orchard.ContentManagement;
using Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers;
using Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers;
using Orchard.Event.Models;

namespace Orchard.Event.Drivers
{
    public class EventPartDriver : ContentPartDriver<EventPart>
    {
        protected override string Prefix
        {
            get
            { return "Event"; }
        }

        protected override DriverResult Editor(EventPart part, dynamic shapeHelper)
        {
            return ContentShape("Parts_Event_Edit", () => shapeHelper
                .EditorTemplate(TemplateName: "Parts/Event", Model: part,     Prefix: Prefix));
    }

    protected override DriverResult Editor(EventPart part, IUpdateModel updater, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        updater.TryUpdateModel(part, Prefix, null, null);
        return Editor(part, shapeHelper);
    }

    protected override DriverResult Display(EventPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        return ContentShape("Parts_Event",
            () => shapeHelper.Parts_Event(
                EventName: part.EventName,
                EventID: part.EventID,
                Description: part.Description
                ));
    }
}
```

}

Placement.info:

```
<Placement>
<place Parts_Event="Content:10"/>
<place Parts_Event_Edit="Content:7.5"/>
</Placement>
```

any ideas would be greatly appreciated; I've compared these with the tutorials and everything seems to be correct on paper.

Comment: Shouldn't the editor view be under Views/EditorTemplates/Parts?

Comment: Sorry; I neglected to write it out fully--it is in EditorTemplates/Parts.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that are wrong:

1. Your editor view should be in the `Views/EditorTemplates/Parts` as Bertrand suggested in the comments
2. You haven't added the handler for the part - see more info here - http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-a-module-with-a-simple-text-editor#AddingaHandler